# How to find wrong script

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, console

I am trying to add some functionality to a web template. After integration of some jQuery plug-ins, some of the functions don't work as expected. When I monitor the code during the process of state changes (for example a sliding effect) there are some CSS properties that cause problems. I need to find which script execution made this change. How can I monitor JavaScript actions and the execution process?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev could you please put that in answer section so that I can mark it as best answer